# How do I iterate through images using file_create_url()?

Tags: 7, media

I am trying to add Lightbox feature to images. This is the code I used in the node template.

```
<p>
<a class="lightbox" href="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_images['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
 <?php print render($content['field_images']); ?>
</a>
</p>
```

This works fine if I have the "field_image" limited to 1 value, but in my case the field_image can have several values (the user can upload several images).

For the first image `$node->field_images['und'][0]['uri'])` is correct; for the second image the path would be `$node->field_images['und'][1]['uri'])`.

So how should I iterate through multiple images?

**UPDATE**(per @Clive feedback):
Here is my updated code:

```
<?php if ( ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_images')) ) {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
   $uri = $item['uri']; ?>
 <p>
<a class="lightbox" href="<?php print $uri ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
<?php print render($content['field_images']); ?>
</a>
</p>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```

I have 2 issues with it: The URL is not correct per my comment below. Second on every iteration it prints all images. For example if I have 2 images: it prints {img1/url1, img2/url1} and then on the next iteration it prints {img1/url2, img2/url2} instead of img1/url1 on the first iteration and then on the second iteration img2/url2.

How would I modify the 'print render($content[]);' to print partial content?

How  would I modify the $uri to print the full URL path?

**UPDATE2**(per @Rupesh feedback):
Here is my updated code:

```
<?php if ( ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_images')) ) {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
   $uri = $item['uri']; ?>
 <p>
<a class="lightbox" href="<?php print file_create_url($uri); ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
<?php print render($content['field_images']); ?>
</a>
</p>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```

Now the only issue I have is that on every iteration it prints all images. For example if I have 2 images: it prints {img1/url1, img2/url1} and then on the next iteration it prints {img1/url2, img2/url2} instead of img1/url1 on the first iteration and then on the second iteration img2/url2.

Now I need I modify the 'print render($content[]);' to print a partial content on every iteration. For example on first iteration it will be `print render($content[][0]);` and on second iteration it will be `print render($content[][1]);` etc.

Something like that (it does not work, with a blank page )

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($content['field_images']); $i++):  
 print render($content['field_images'][$i]); ?>
 endfor; 
?>
```

The count is wrong, it outputs 17 instead of just 2 images.
What would I change in in the code above to get it to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours of frustration. Here is my solution to my question.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++):  ?>
<p>
<a class="lightbox" href="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_images['und'][$i]['uri']); ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
<?php print render($content['field_images'][$i]); ?>
</a>
</p>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I hardcoded $i (not ideal), since I am limiting the number of images that can be uploaded. 
Not ideal, but it works.
Also `count($content['field_images']);` returns 17 instead of the actual number of images of 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), but Drupal has a specific function for this, [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7):

```
if ( ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_images')) ) {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $uri = $item['uri'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I am closer to a solution. Now `print $uri` outputs the image link as `public://images/circuits/image1.jpg` but I want to output the full path of the image, i.e:`http://domain/sites/default/files/images/circuits/image1.jpg` So how would I change the code to get the Full URL?

Comment: @Boutros Go throuh this link https://drupal.org/node/837794. This post answer your question.

Comment: @Rupesh, thank you. I got this one solved. `file_create_url($uri);` did the trick and converts it to the url path.